# cypher query to find Employee nodes who have all the Skills

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a cypher query to find the first name of 'Employee' nodes who 'Has' all the Skills (have relationship with all the nodes with the 'Skill' label). This is my data model:

[image]

I managed to get all the employee nodes that have at least one relationship with skill nodes, but I do not want this. This is the cypher query:

```
:match (a:employee)-[r:Has_Skill]->(b:profession) return a,r,band
```

I couldn't write it with the `ALL()` function. 
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Did you tried the syntax like here? https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Aside: Your Cypher query uses node labels and relationship types that do not match your illustrated data model. So, I will ignore your illustration.*

This is a slightly tricky way to get the `employee` nodes that have `Has_Skill` relationships to all `profession` nodes:

```
MATCH (p:profession)
WITH COUNT(p) AS pCount
MATCH (employee:employee)-[r:Has_Skill]->()
WITH pCount, employee, COUNT(r) AS sCount
WHERE sCount = pCount
RETURN employee;
```

The query gets the number of `profession` nodes and returns employees that have that number of skills.

*By the way, you will get much better support for neo4j questions at stackoverflow.com.*